# Can we set a CSS animation to happen after the previous child element animated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Imagine I have ten li element under the same ul element. I want to do, say a slide in effect. Currently, we can easily do that with css animation, but if I want the animation to happen in a sequence, it doesn't seem to have an obvious way to do it.

I am also open to a javascript hybrid solution as lone as it's relatively fast (for smart phones). Thanks!

Comment: You’re looking for `animation-delay` maybe …?

Comment: That's my current solution. I have to manually add that to each element. It's doable when I only have three elements but when there are ten or more, it becomes hard to manage.

Comment: _“but when there are ten or more, it becomes hard to manage”_ – you have heard that computers are able to execute things called “scripts”, that can do that for you, right …?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a recursive function. I'll use jQuery for this. in this code the animation is just adding margin to the left. you can edit the animation for your preference

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <ul>
    <li id="li-1">List Item 1</li>
    <li id="li-2">List Item 2</li>
    <li id="li-3">List Item 3</li>
    <li id="li-4">List Item 4</li>
    <li id="li-5">List Item 5</li>
    <li id="li-6">List Item 6</li>
    <li id="li-7">List Item 7</li>
    <li id="li-8">List Item 8</li>
    <li id="li-9">List Item 9</li>
    <li id="li-10">List Item 10</li>
    </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function slideLi(curLi) {
    console.log(curLi);

    if($("#li-"+curLi).length) {

        $("#li-"+curLi).animate({
            marginLeft: "+=50px"
        }, 200, "linear", function() {
            $(this).animate({
                marginLeft: "-=50px"
            }, 200, "linear", function() {
                slideLi(curLi-1);
            });
        });
        return;
    } else return;
    }

    $("ul").mouseenter(function() {
    slideLi($("ul li").length);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool. Would be better if there is more css method.

Comment: check out other options for [animate][http://api.jquery.com/animate/] method in jquery.